# Select data from database when Drop-downlist value is selected. FileMaker

Tags: filemaker

I have a FileMaker form and I am trying to find a way in which I can select a value from the Dropdown list and it will drag related values from my database and populate the rest of the forms fields based on the data related to this value. I am rather new to FileMaker but have an understanding of scripts and believe I may need to use one for this.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks:)

Comment: I am guessing(!) you want  to do a [lookup](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help%2Flookups.html%23).  But perhaps all you need is to place the related fields on the layout. It's hard to tell from such a laconic description. --  P.S. This type of question is much better suited to one of the forums dedicated to the Filemaker platform. There you can have a discussion, even exchange files if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to select related or non related records from another table in the same FileMaker DB you have few options, my suggestion is either a card window showing records from that table you need the data from or a popover, for the later you need to create relationships and filter the portal.